# PayPal Integration (Sandbox) Amount Display

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am able to integrate Paypal (SandBox), but facing a small issue.
I am not able to see amount getting displayed in the InContext pop up window, when I use,
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=token&useraction=continue;
In this case Review Window button Name is Continue.

When I use 
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=token&useraction=commit;
I am able to see the amount in the In Context pop up window, but in the review page the Button name changes to Pay Now.

I am passing all the required fields when calling the setExpressCheckOut method
as below

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&VERSION=113.0
&PWD=Password
&USER=User
&SIGNATURE=Signature
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&RETURNURL=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/returnUrl
&CANCELURL=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/cancelUrl
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$46.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&NOSHIPPING=1
&SILENTTRAN=TRUE
&HDRIMG=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/resources/images/logo.jpg
&ALLOWNOTE=0
&CHANNELTYPE=Merchant
&BRANDNAME=ABC
```

I need to Display Continue button in the Review Page along with Amount.
Am i missing something or is there any other way i can achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to display the amount,
added the below parameters while calling the setExpressCheckout
a. PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT
b. L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0

The calling the setExpressCheckOut method is as below

```
https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp?METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&VERSION=113.0
&PWD=Password
&USER=User
&SIGNATURE=Signature
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&RETURNURL=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/returnUrl
&CANCELURL=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/cancelUrl
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$46.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&NOSHIPPING=1
&SILENTTRAN=TRUE
&HDRIMG=http://localhost:8080/PayGeo/resources/images/logo.jpg
&ALLOWNOTE=0
&CHANNELTYPE=Merchant
&BRANDNAME=ABC
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=$46.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$46.00
```

Hope it helps some one.